# Unable to connect to Virtual Machine Webserver

Tags: vmware, nat, centos7, vmware-workstation

I have installed Cent OS 7 inside my vmware and selected the network type as NAT. Everything is fine. The ip assigned to vmware cent OS is `192.168.137.130`. I am able to connect to `192.168.137.130` from outside that means from my windows os on putty via port 22. I am able to ping. I am able to telnet to port 80 (httpd is running). But I am unable to connect via browser to  `192.168.137.130`.

```
192.168.130.1
```

When I type this I am able to connect to my windows webserver. What I have done wrong. Please help.